# After copying records from a Char column to a Varchar column, I'm unable to find the row using like statement in SQL Server 2014 but fine in 2003

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

After copying records from a `Char` column to a `Varchar` column, I'm unable to find the row using `like` statement

```
Create database testDB
Go

USE [testDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable1]
(
    [Col_char] [char](20) NULL,
    [Col_nchar] [nchar](64) NULL,
    [Col_varchar] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [Col_nvarchar] [nvarchar](64) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

insert into TestTable1 values ('Sumit1%', 'Sumit1%', 'Sumit1%', 'Sumit1%')
insert into TestTable1 values ('Sumit2*', 'Sumit2*', null, 'Sumit2*')

select 
    [Col_char], LEN([Col_char]),
    [Col_nchar], LEN([Col_nchar]),
    [Col_varchar], LEN([Col_varchar]),
    [Col_nvarchar], LEN([Col_nvarchar]) 
from 
    TestTable1
```

This line is giving me the search result

```
select * 
from TestTable1 
where 'sumit1' like [Col_varchar]
```

Now I am replacing `*` with `%` & copying [Col_char] to [Col_varchar] column

```
update TestTable1 
set [Col_varchar] = Replace([Col_char], '*', '%')
where [Col_char] like '%2%'

select * from TestTable1

select * from TestTable1 where 'sumit1' like [Col_varchar]

-- this line is not showing any results 
select * from TestTable1 where 'sumit2' like [Col_varchar]

select 
    Len(Replace([Col_char], '*', '%')),
    Len(Replace([Col_varchar], '*', '%')), * 
from TestTable1
```

Comment: A great example of a well formulated example and question

Comment: your example works fine for me.. as long as you leave off  `SET ANSI_PADDING ON` at the beginning of the query

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for identifiers (e.g column names), as defined by ANSI SQL. (SQL Server also has square brackets.)

Answer (score 5):

When you have `SET ANSI_PADDING ON`  a `CHAR(20)` will always be 20 characters by padding the right side with spaces.

When you convert that to varchar you still have 20 characters so your `Col_varchar` value is actually `"Sumit2%             "`  so you're looking for a string that starts with `Sumit2` but also has a bunch of spaces at the end

if you replace the value using

```
UPDATE
    TestTable1
SET 
    [Col_varchar] = RTRIM(REPLACE([Col_char],'*','%'))
WHERE
    [Col_char] LIKE '%2%'
```

it should work for you.

Info on ANSI_PADDING https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx

Comment: Thank you JamieD77, It helped me .. :)